# Expendable Item with LazyColumn is not smooth while scrolling in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I get lists from API and display them in `LazyColumn` with the expendable scroll. All list items are initially in a not expended state and while the user clicks them, I want to show the detail of that item in the expendable item view.

When my list items are in expended state, scrolling is smooth but when the initial state ( not expended ) scrolling is not smooth. I saved expendable state with `rememberSavable` and update when user clicks the item.

These are my code:

My `viewModel`

```
@HiltViewModel
class MainViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val appRepository: AppRepository
) : ViewModel() {

    val breeds: Flow<PagingData<BreedItem>> = Pager(
        config = PagingConfig(pageSize = 3)
    ) {
        BreedsPagingDataSource(appRepository)
    }.flow.cachedIn(viewModelScope)
}
```

My `ListScreen`

```
@Composable
fun DoggoListScreen() {
    val vm: MainViewModel = hiltViewModel()
    DoggoListView(
        breedItems = vm.breeds,
    )
}
```

My `ListView`

```
@Composable
fun DoggoListView(
    breedItems: Flow<PagingData<BreedItem>>,
) {

    val breed: LazyPagingItems<BreedItem> = breedItems.collectAsLazyPagingItems()

    LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(4.dp)
    ) {

        items(breed) { item ->
            FoldAbleItem(
                item!!.toVo(),
                onClick = {
                    //todo : do some click action
                })
        }
        breed.apply {

            when {
                loadState.refresh is LoadState.Loading -> {
                    item {
                        LoadingView(modifier = Modifier.fillParentMaxSize())
                    }
                }
                loadState.append is LoadState.Loading -> {
                    item {
                        LoadingItem()
                    }
                }
                loadState.refresh is LoadState.Error -> {
                    val e = breed.loadState.refresh as LoadState.Error
                    item {
                        ErrorItem(
                            message = e.error.localizedMessage!!,
                            modifier = Modifier.fillParentMaxSize(),
                            onClickRetry = { retry() }
                        )
                    }
                }
                loadState.append is LoadState.Error -> {
                    val e = breed.loadState.append as LoadState.Error
                    item {
                        ErrorItem(
                            message = e.error.localizedMessage!!,
                            onClickRetry = { retry() }
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My `ItemView`

```
@Composable
fun FoldAbleItem(
    breed: Breed,
    onClick: () -> Unit
) {
    //you can save expandedState by remember if you don't want to save it across scrolling
    var expandedState by rememberSaveable {
        mutableStateOf(breed.isExpended)
    }

    val rotationState by animateFloatAsState(
        targetValue = if (expandedState) 180f else 0f
    )
    val image = rememberCoilPainter(
        request = breed.url,
        fadeIn = true,
        fadeInDurationMs = 500
    )

    Card(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(4.dp)
            .animateContentSize(
                animationSpec = tween(
                    durationMillis = 300,
                    easing = LinearOutSlowInEasing
                )
            )
            .clickable(
                onClick = onClick
            ),
        shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.medium,
    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(12.dp)
        ) {
            Row(
                verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
            ) {
                Text(
                    modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
                    text = breed.name,
                    maxLines = 1,
                    overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.h5
                )
                IconButton(
                    modifier = Modifier.rotate(rotationState),
                    onClick = { expandedState = !expandedState }
                ) {
                    Icon(
                        imageVector = Icons.Default.ArrowDropDown,
                        contentDescription = "Drop Arrow"
                    )
                }
            }

            if (expandedState) {
                Text(
                    text = breed.temperament ?: "movie.bred_for",
                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.body2
                )
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(8.dp))

                Image(
                    painter = image,
                    contentDescription = null,
                    //16:9 = 1.7f
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .aspectRatio(1.7f, false)
                        .clip(MaterialTheme.shapes.medium)
                    ,
                    contentScale = ContentScale.FillWidth
                )

                breed.description?.let {
                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(8.dp))
                    Text(
                        text = it,
                        style = MaterialTheme.typography.body2
                    )
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I think I am doing well with implementation `LazyColumn` and `DataSet`. But I am not sure with the expendable state in `rememberSavable`. Please emphersize the part.

```
//you can save expandedState by remember if you don't want to save it across scrolling
var expandedState by rememberSaveable {
    mutableStateOf(breed.isExpended)
}

val rotationState by animateFloatAsState(
    targetValue = if (expandedState) 180f else 0f
)
val image = rememberCoilPainter(
    request = breed.url,
    fadeIn = true,
    fadeInDurationMs = 500
)
```

Comment: Have you tried running Release version of the app? `LazyColumn` is much less performant during Debug

Comment: Ahh. I dont do tried release version yet. Thank you so much. @PhilipDukhov

Comment: @Philip Dukov , bro Its not work as I expected when I build release ver.

Comment: I'm not sure what else could be wrong, the code seems fine. In such cases, I remove the code part by part to see what's causing the problem

Comment: I have done as you say. I removed my expended state, it's fine with scrolling. When I add that my lazy column does not scroll well. Also, I make all of my items in expended state, it's ok too. I really don't know what was wrong with this. :P Thank you for your advice.

Comment: Hi @Philip Dukhov , if you have time and are interested in my problem, you can check my sample repo. :D This is my repo. https://github.com/kyawlinnthant/Paging3WithCompose

Comment: I had the same problem about a year ago, as far as I remember, when I put all the "expandable" content in a separate composable, the problem was solved. (In my case it was AmimatedVisibility)

Comment: I have tried with AnimatedVisibility, but still not smooth bro. @bylazy